# Texture Atlas Not Found with SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit, texturepacker

I am playing with Sprite Kit and trying to embed a texture atlas into the game. Everything works without problems when I test the game on "iPhone Retina (4-inch 64bit)" simulator. But when I switch to another simulator (Retina 3.5-inch and Retina 4-inch) the app crashes with the error "Texture Atlas Not Found". It seems like it has something to do with the device being 64bit but I don't have enough knowledge to make any comments.

PS: I created the atlas with TexturePacker but tried this both with XCode atlases and TexturePacker atlases. Same results.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I narrowed down the problem a bit. SKAction is the problem here. As soon as SpriteKit starts the animation I get the error above. If I comment the lines with the animation, I can see the textures on the screen, no problems there.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    SKTexture *tex = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"creature-1/explode/%03d", i]];
    [textures addObject:tex];
}

SKAction *critAnim = [SKAction animateWithTextures:textures timePerFrame:0.3];
[critSprite runAction:critAnim completion:^{
    [critSprite removeFromParent];
}];
[self addChild:critSprite];
```

Comment: The atlas is in your bundle (ie added as resource or folder reference to the xcode project)? Make sure you delete the app from the device/simulator before testing again, it's possible it works on one simulator but not the other simply because the app's bundle still contained an older texture atlas (xcode will never remove files from an already deployed bundle).

Comment: Removing the app solved the problem, thanks!